# Query error in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've tried this code to update all my values in column sync to 0...
How can I solve this issue?

```
public boolean updatesync()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.rawQuery("update patients set sync = '0'",null);

    return true;
}
```

This code is not working. I need to change the entire column value of sync to 0. How can I do that? I've found this code as working when searching, but it's not working for me. How can I solve that?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `execSQL()` instead of `rawQuery()`.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but does not execute it until the returned `Cursor` is moved. `execSQL()` both compiles and executes the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

for update value in Sqlite , try this one

```
public int updateName(string name,String Id){  
       ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
           args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
   return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + Id, null) > 0;
}

  *** Note *** 
  KEY_NAME= Column name (value will update),
  DATABASE_TABLE =Table name ,
  KEY_ROWID = Column name (value will update depends on this column name)
```